# hibernate does not work on cloned system

Tags: suspend, hibernate

I cloned a 17.10 ubuntu root partition with the cp command to a new SSD into a new partition. Everything is ok except hibernation. I can suspend to disk. But when I start the system, it just does a normal boot, not a resume.

Now I did the following test: I hibernated the new system, then I booted the old system using the swap partition of the new systen. And the old system resumed and was where the new system hibernated.

So the new system does hibernate correctly, but it does not resume. It just ignores the hibernate data in the swap partition.

I guess this is due to the fact that I did not copy the /dev directory to the new partition because I thought /dev does not contain real files. But maybe it contains links that are missing now?

Comment: Hibernation on an SSD drive is often considered problematic. https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/disable-hibernate-ssd-warranty-purposes/ http://www.thessdreview.com/forums/threads/hibernation-turn-off-why-except-for-capacity.4370/ https://www.pcworld.com/article/2043634/how-to-stretch-the-life-of-your-ssd-storage.html https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-ssds-solid-state-drives-work-increase-lifespan/

Answer (score 1):

Solved it:

- update /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume with the correct swap partition
- sudo update-initramfs -u